# How do I make a Kotlin list mutable, add items, and then iterate over the resulting immutable list?

Tags: kotlin, immutability, mutability, immutablelist

Essentially I need to start with an immutable list of a few items, convert it to a mutable list and add a few items, and then iterate over it with `firstOrNull`. Here's my scratch file:

```kotlin
val immutableStarter = listOf(1, 2, 3)

val mutable = immutableStarter.toMutableList()
mutable.add(4)
mutable.addAll(listOf(5, 6, 7))
mutable.add(8)

println(mutable)

val result = mutable.firstOrNull { item ->
    println("Checking Item $item")
    item > 7
} ?: 0

println(result)
```

The `println(mutable)` call correctly prints the list with all eight items. However, it seems the `firstOrNull` operation is only running on the first three items in the list. I only get the `"Checking Item $item"` output three times. If I add a fourth item to the `immutableStarter` it checks four times. So the best I can gather, for some reason, it's only iterating over the items in the initial, immutable starting list.

If I wrap lines 10-15 in a `try`/`catch` or with `run`, I get the output I would expect - a `"Checking Item $item"` printout for each of the 8 items in the list.

Why isn't this working as I have it written, and what is it about wrapping the `firstOrNull` call in a `try`/`catch` or `run` that makes it work?

================================================

**EDIT:** Someone asked for the output of my scratch file. Here it is:

```
Checking Item 1
Checking Item 2
Checking Item 3
val immutableStarter: List<Int>

val mutable: MutableList<Int>
true
true
true

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


val result: Int


0
```

It looks like it may be an issue with how scratch files are evaluated - it looks like IntelliJ may be attempting to evaluate the scratch file asynchronously. Toggling the `Use REPL` checkbox at the top of IntelliJ, for example, gives me the output I'd expect:

```
res2: kotlin.Boolean = true
res3: kotlin.Boolean = true
res4: kotlin.Boolean = true

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]



Checking Item 1
Checking Item 2
Checking Item 3
Checking Item 4
Checking Item 5
Checking Item 6
Checking Item 7
Checking Item 8

8
```

Comment: Could you please post your output? cause I'm getting it correctly with `Checking Item...` printed 8 times.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Absolutely - just added my output and some further theories on why I'm seeing these results.

Comment: Putting this in a `main` method and running it via IntelliJ or doing `kotlinc` then `kotlin` to run it both work fine for me.